# How to test Google Play Billing V5 One time Promo Codes for Subscriptions at an accelerated rate?

Tags: android, subscription, google-play-billing, promotion-code

I am trying to test Google One-Time Promo Codes for Subscriptions. Like they suggest in https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/test#promo and https://developer.android.com/guide/playpoints/test. I want to test how promo codes are applied out side of the app but, I need to test all of the different scenarios to make sure we are correctly applying the subscriptions in the backend when a one-time codes are used outside of the app.

These documents makes it seem like this is possible.

So what I have done

- create an app and integrate the billing library v5.
- Added a subscription to be purchased in that app.
- Then became a licensed tester for that app.
  When I open the app a start the purchase flow for the subscription I see the accelerated time frame of the subscriptions. ( 3mins for a free trial, 5mins for a month ... ect ) As well as the Test Card, Always Approves.
- Then I leave the app and open the Play store to apply a one time Promo code in the redeem code screen in Payments & subscriptions.
- I see the promo code get applied in the Play store UI but the UI seems to suggest the promo is in real time ( meaning a promo code for a 7 day free trial is 7 days long ). But the subscription is still in 5 min intervals.

[Image showing Promo code Free trial is 7 days and subscription intervals after are 5 mins](https://i.stack.imgur.com/87goe.png)

Is there any way to make promo codes follow the same rules as the accelerated time as subscriptions do, so we can test integrations with our backends?  To make sure promo codes and subscriptions are correctly updated?

If this is not possible how are others testing these promo code scenarios if they can only apply a one promo once?

Answer (score -3):

I think Test subscriptions renew more quickly than actual subscriptions, and test subscriptions renew a maximum of six times.

**in table Time-based subscription features clearly explained :**

Purchase acknowledgement            5 minutes
Grace period (both 3- and 7-day)    5 minutes
ETC.

I think you must call a customer service from googla play store for details or for request what you want.

**You can Direct Message to twitter:**
https://twitter.com/AndroidDev

Or

**Google Community**
https://developers.google.com/community/gdg?hl=en

Comment: Note that the question is about promo codes: "Is there any way to make **promo codes** follow the same rules as the accelerated time as subscriptions do" (emphasis added).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).